# Using RestSharp to request a URL with Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I have a web site in IIS that its Authentication mode is set to `Windows`.
I need to call a URL in that site using [restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) :

```
var client = new RestClient(item.Url);
var request = new RestRequest("/account/Menu", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("SSO_Token", token);
client.PreAuthenticate = false;
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.NtlmAuthenticator(new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
// I also tried following codes with no luck:
// client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.NtlmAuthenticator();
// client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

now the problem is I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I'm sure the provided credential is correct.

Comment: I was having the exactly same problem. But it turned out that Windows Authentication was turned off accidentally at server. It may sound silly but you may want to double check the server configuration. The code works perfectly for me.

Comment: Are you sure that windows authentication means NTLM in your case and not Kerberos?

Comment: Whats the authentication mode for the Rest API ? JWT or Basic or Windows Authentication ?

Comment: I know that credentials look to be correct in this case, but worth noting for others (from experience with people who "know the credentials are correct") has been failed request tracing on the IIS server. Once enabled, these logs let you decrypt a base 64 encoded password (in the trace, after the word basic). That way it's easy to find any potential encoding issues, or bad requests from other users.

Link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/4043926/Why-is-my-API-throws-an-error-when-using-authentic

```
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```